# Drawing circles of variable size and position on a 2d animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am working with matplotlib in Python 3.3. I have an animated 2d and 3d window, on which I draw points. These points represent objects, but it is not certain that they are actually there. So I want to draw a circle around these points to display the uncertainty. This uncertainty is variating, so bottomline: I want to draw multiple (might be 0, might be 100) circkles in a 2D animation with a variable center and a variable radius.

I tried scatter. Scatter looks very promising, until I resize the screen: the size of the scatter is in pixels and not related to the size of the axes. Any idea how I can do this?

I have tried the following scatter code:

```
#In the init
self.circles = self.ax.scatter([],[],[],c = 'b',alpha=0.6)
#In the animate function
self.circles.set_offsets([[10],[15]])    
self.circles._sizes = [2000]
```

The centerpoint is correct, at x = 10 and y = 15. But the size is the size in pixels and not related to the axes. In this case I expected the circle to hit x = 10 and y = 20015, for example. But it does not.

This becomes a problem when I resize the window.

Comment: What do you mean the size is in pixels? The circle size? Can you please show your code?

Comment: Added some code to the text.

Comment: This is a 'feature' of scatter.  Look at how scatter works underneath, it is just a collection of path objects.  I would do the same with `Circle` patch objects which you can size in data units.

Comment: Can I use circels the same way I can use things like scatter and line?

Comment: see http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle + `ax.add_*` + the collection objects.

Comment: That is awesome. Completely different then I imagined, but it works like a charm. I create a global list of the circkels I want and add this list to the axis object. On the next animation cycle I call remove() on every object in this list, empty the list and refill it with every circle I want. Rinse and repeat, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: A) could you please write that up as an answer? B) you might do better speed wise to re-size/move existing circles.  Doing it that way will let you use blitting.

Comment: Well, maybe. That would be more, unobvious code in a test program so for now this is okay. When we switch to a different language to create the production version I will reconsider, but for now this is more then fast enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing `Collections` is faster, so I modified the `draw()` function of the `PathCollection` object returned by `scatter()`. The new `draw()` uses `transData` to calculate the scale of every circle, it uses the size of every circle as diameter.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import Collection
from matplotlib import transforms
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = pl.figure()

N = 40
x, y = np.random.rand(2, N)
color = np.random.rand(N)
r = np.random.rand(N) * 0.05 + 0.05

c = pl.scatter(x, y, s=r, c=color, alpha=0.5, animated=True)
pl.gca().set_aspect("equal")

def draw(self, renderer):
    if self._sizes is not None:
        m = self.axes.transData.get_matrix()
        self._transforms = [
            transforms.Affine2D().scale(m[0, 0]*x, m[1, 1]*x)
            for x in self._sizes]
    return Collection.draw(self, renderer)

c.draw = lambda renderer:draw(c, renderer)

def update_loc(n):
    global x2, y2, x, y
    n = n % 50
    if n == 0:
        x2, y2 = np.random.rand(2, N)
    x += (x2 - x) * 0.1
    y += (y2 - y) * 0.1
    c.set_offsets(np.c_[x, y])
    return c,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_loc, 2500, interval=50, blit=True)

pl.show()
```

Here is a frame of the animation:

[image]

Comment: Very Nice! I will test this asap and if it works, you get the green 'v'.

Answer (score 0):

Tcaswell wrote the answer in the comments above, so if you want to upvote this, upvote him too.

The fix was to use a circle: http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle. These work very different from the axis.plot and axis.scatter in the sens that to add them you have to do the following:

```
i = pyplot.Circle((item["x"],item["y"]), radius=item["inaccuracy"], fc='None'))
self.ax.add_patch(i)
```

And to remove them:

```
i.remove()
```

tcaswell also suggested that instead of removing every circle before drawing a new set of circles you can also just move and resize i. Which is indeed very possible: just change the `radius` and `xy` propertes of `i`. I have not tested this, but it is not hard to imagine that this will be faster then removing all existing circles and adding all new ones.